# How to break while loop?

Tags: java, android, loops

In my service i have the below code and i want to break the loop when flag is set to true. It works well except when internet connection is slow or poor. Then as it sticks to the download part, the loop won't break efficiently. Any workarounds?
A solution is using a timer which periodically (every 500 ms) checks the flag state. But i don't know how to break the loop when the flag is set to true!

```
static boolean flag = false;

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {              
    new Thread (new Runnable (){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            foo();
        }
    }).start();      
    return START_STICKY;
}

void foo(){      
    try{            
        while(true){
            if (flag)
                return;
            //download some data which takes a few seconds
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try making the flag as volatile : volatile static boolean flag = false;  Always its value will be read from the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `break;` keyword to break out of a loop. So for you it might look something like this in your loop:

```
if(condition) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: It's not a matter of break or return. I need to exit while when it's stuck in downloading process. Is there a way?

Comment: @Charanor , If you see the code posted in the question by solo, there is already a 'return' statement in place of break, which anyways will break the loop.

Comment: By your question I'm guessing by "stuck" you mean taking too much time - then I would suggest you check for how long the download has been running and if it's above, lets say 1 second you either ´return;´ or ´break;´ the code.